# Using typescript classes for services in angular 1.4.7

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement services as classes as per this Ng Conf video *Angular 1.3 meets Angular 2.0 - Michał Gołębiowski*:

https://youtu.be/pai1ZdFI2dg?t=4m25s

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```

Code below:

```
var angular = window['angular'];
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .service('myService', [MyService])
    .directive('test', function (myService) {
        return {
            restricts: 'E',
            template: 'Directive output: {{ctrl.message}}',
            controllerAs: 'ctrl',
            controller: function () {
                this.message = myService.message;
            }   
        }
    });

/*
// Works
function MyService () {
  return {
      message: "service test"
    }
}
*/

// Does not work
class MyService {
  public message:string;
  constructor () {
    this.message = "service test by class";
  }
}
```

http://codepen.io/AshCoolman/pen/PPLONm?editors=001

**EDIT: Solution**

Simple wrapping the class works, and that will do for now:

```
.service('myService', function () {return new MyService()})
```

Actually it seems quite straight forward now I think of it. The example video is using es6 perhaps with Babel, while I'm using Typescript. *At a guess*, Typescript/Tracuer is probably doing things differently. I will look into this later tonight and post a full explanation.

**EDIT: Explanation**

Martin Vseticka beat me to it, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
.service('myService', [MyService])
```

should be

```
.service('myService', MyService)
```

**Edit:** The solution is more simple I guess :-) The approach with

```
function MyService () {
  return {
      message: "service test"
    }
}
```

works because functions are [hoisted](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html) in JavaScript.

However, the following TypeScript code

```
class MyService {
  public message:string;
  constructor () {
    this.message = "service test by class";
  }
}
```

is transpiled to:

```
var MyService = (function () {
    function MyService() {
        this.message = "service test by class";
    }
    return MyService;
})();
```

which means that `.service('myService', MyService)` cannot work because `MyService` is not defined (i.e. `MyService = undefined`) at that point!

Comment: Ah yes, that looks odd, but its just the remenants of injection annotations I removed for the example. Previously `.service('myService', ['$http', MyService])`. It doesnt seem to be the problem.

Comment: Hoisting, shoulda guessed >_< Thanks mate